# Datadog synthetic tests: How do I enable cookies?

Tags: cookies, e2e-testing, datadog, synthetic

I am trying to create a synthetic test on a site that requires cookies enabled in order to work.

If cookies are not enabled, user is prompted with an error message saying they need cookies enabled.

What options do I have of implementing my test?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the browser test, under **Advanced Options** you can define the necessary cookies use the [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header syntax.

[image: a screenshot of the advance options]